# Show local branches which are not existent on origin

Tags: git

I'm looking for a Git command to show me all local branches which do not exist on the origin.

In other words, I want to know which branches `git fetch -p` would prune.

Comment: Just a note: `git fetch -p` clears remote tracking branches that are **no longer** existing on the remote. This has nothing to do with local branches. The command removes remote branches that are no longer existing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's usually the `-n` or [`--dry-run`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) flags for most git commands. They show you what they would be doing, without actually doing it.

> `--dry-run`
>
> Show what would be done, without making any changes.